# I want to build ajob in pentaho

Tags: hadoop, pentaho

I want to build a pentaho job in which there is a hadoop query through which i need to pull the data and then load that data in a csv file.Then I need to post that file to a FTP server.Could anybody please help me with the steps that I need to use from pentaho?

Comment: You need to put some details of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

For using hadoop and pdi, Pentaho Mapreduce step to read the data from the hdfs file and then use Mapreduce input to process the data. You can check this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/hadoop-wordcount-using-pentaho-data-integrationkettle/) for more.

Next you need to use "[Put a file with SFTP](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Put+a+file+with+SFTP)" steps in pentaho job to finally place the file to your respective path.

Hope this helps :)